# Использование feed.image.title в feedparser

Tags: python-3.x, парсер

Не очень понятно как вытянуть изображение из `rss`, используя `feed.image.title`.

Как это сделать? Приведите небольшой пример пожалуйста.

`title`, `link` вытаскиваются без проблем.

вот так выглядит rss

```
<title>Blablabla</title> <guid isPermaLink="true">https://st.xxx/es/59255.html</guid> <link>https://st.xxx/es/59255.html</link> <dc:creator>caddoc</dc:creator> <description><![CDATA[ <img alt="" height="250" width="250" src="https://ext.st.xxx/250s/6f9-f2198169675c.jpg"/>
```

нужна последняя ссылка с изображением

код такой

```
import feedparser

feed = feedparser.parse("http://st.xxx/rss/")

feed_title = feed['feed']['title']
feed_entries = feed.entries

for entry in feed.entries:
    article_title = entry.title
    article_link = entry.link
    article_img = entry.description # На данный момент эта строка выводит все что есть в описании, именно оттуда мне необходимо вытащить ссылку на картинку, у каждого поста своя картинка
    article_author = entry.author
    print("----------------------------------------------\n"
    "Описание:", article_title, "\n"
    "Ссылка:", article_link, "\n"
    "Автор:", article_author, "\n"
    "IMG:", article_img, "\n")
```

Comment: приведите минимальный но полный пример rss (пример в вопросе не является корректным xml документном)

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался

```
import feedparser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

feed = feedparser.parse("http://st.xxx/rss/")
feed_entries = feed.entries

for entry in feed_entries:
    article_title = entry.title
    article_link = entry.link
    soup = BeautifulSoup(entry.summary)
    article_img = soup.find('img')['src']
    article_author = ("#" + entry.author)
    print("----------------------------------------------\n"
    "Описание:", article_title, "\n"
    "Ссылка:", article_link, "\n"
    "Автор:", article_author, "\n"
    "IMG:", article_img, "\n")
```

Comment: В вопросе картинка была в теге `description`, спрятанная в CDATA, а тут у вас в `summary`, можете привести пример rss-текста в ответе?

Comment: вывод вот такой
----------------------------------------------
    Описание: Blablabla
    Ссылка: https://st.xxx/blog/agss/159252.html
    Автор: #Sheght
    IMG: https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB17d8SaVTM8KJjSZFAq6yexXXaG/ck-and.jpg

Comment: @gil9red Подскажите пожалуйста в чем моя ошибка. и как спарсить используя CDATA

Comment: Ссылка на html недоступна. Просто, я попробовал парсить `<description>` и вот что вышло: https://pastebin.com/12QFT5fN